# How should I handle a user who continually comments under my answer? I feel like I'm being harassed

Tags: support, comments, harassment

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40614963/4756299) is basically an indirect simple quote from Hans Boehm to the question [**Is a global implicitly volatile in C?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614016/is-a-global-implicitly-volatile-in-c).  I pointed out that `volatile` doesn't really do much for multithreaded programming—because it doesn't.

This answer has apparently attracted the attention of a user who, over the past couple of days, has posted comments containing words such as:

> "Boehm just avoided doing the obvious observation that volatile prevents all these advanced optimization."

and insulting comments such as:

> "The rejection of volatile is as conditioned as the rejection of goto, and as unfounded, conditioned, irrational, visceral, "holier than you" attitude of people who pretend to know better".

Yesterday's comments were thankfully deleted, but he's back...

I reply with comments along the lines of stating the user has confused `volatile`'s actually semantics of "evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine" with "prevents all optimizations".

The user has claimed to have written multithreaded code using `volatile` and that it works correctly.  I have asked the user to post such code, multiple times.

The user claims he has a question, but I have failed to see it.

This user is coming across to me as very harassing.

Comment: Best course of action? Disengage. Do not reply. Go your way and move past this interaction. If the user keeps posting unwelcome feedback on your post, flag for moderator attention. While you keep moving away.

Comment: @yivi How are contradicting arguments "unwelcome"?

Comment: @curious Unwelcome by the user receiving them. Once you make a point in a comment under  post, if the post author is not receptive to your comments, just move away and leave them alone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204077/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-henle-how-to-handle-continual-repeated-harrass).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, if you're feeling harassed by a user, raise a custom mod flag explaining the situation.

By keeping this in the public light, you just invite more conflict between you and this user. That won't be constructive, but a moderator can be.

Then disengage.

---

In this specific case, both you and the person commenting were both feeling attacked by the other, and were both acting defensively, adding to the problem at hand. There are a couple of tactics you could use if this ever comes up again to help avoid this kind of a conflict:

1. If someone comments on your answer saying it has an error, but you still disagree, instead of trying to convince that person of their mistake in the comments, invite them to post a new answer with the version they think is correct. Since answers can be voted up and down, it's easier to evaluate their quality, compared to comments that only have rising vote counts. Plus, there's more space in the answer to explain their point, so they might actually make a good argument that you agree with when you see it in its complete form. "You seem to believe my solution is not accurate, but I don't understand your argument that you're putting in these comments. Could you make a complete answer explaining what you believe is the right way?"
2. If the person commenting already has an answer, or if an answer exists that contains their argument, then instead of explaining why your answer is correct, edit your answer to explain why it's a better method. That keeps good information in the answer rather than getting it scattered among the comments. If you feel your answer adequately addresses all points the commenter is making, invite them to edit the other answer to be more clear. "I don't see why that would be the case, as far as I can tell my answer does address those points. Could you edit the other answer to explain why you believe my approach is flawed?"

Both of these approaches show even though you're not convinced, you're open to learning, so it's impossible for the person to claim you're attacking them.

Likewise, a person who thinks they see an error with an answer may comment once, consistent with the purpose of comments (To suggest improvements and add more information), but if the person disagrees with you, use an answer to provide a complete one instead of trying to convince that one user of their mistake. Most importantly, stick to the facts and don't use hyperbole (Such as "200% false" and useless descriptors of the existing answer like "unfounded" "irrational"), as that will only serve to provoke the user instead of encouraging them to improve their answer.

Comment: "*invite them to post a new answer*" but what if one *can't* post an answer yet can definitely point out something incorrect? I've been in this situation and it feels exceptionally petty from the other party to just dismiss your critique with the ye olde "If you know better, do it yourself" which has never really held true. I don't need to be a tailor to say clothes don't fit me. I don't need to be a chef to spot a bad dish. I don't need to be able to post an answer to say why one is incorrect. After all, do you even that with QA? "You found a bug, eh? Well, let's see YOU write the code!"

Comment: @VLAZ You don’t have to post an answer just because someone asks. If they seem sincere in wanting to understand your criticism, invite them to discuss it in chat. If not, then disengage.

Comment: To be clear, @VLAZ, this suggestion of posting a competing answer (which I encouraged Davy to add to his answer) is not instead of posting *a* comment. It's instead of engaging in a *debate* in the comments section.

Comment: @VLAZ There's a big difference between "You found the bug, you write the code" which implies the OP recognizes something is wrong but is too lazy to address it, and "I don't think that's a bug, and your explanation doesn't make sense to me, I don't see anything to improve in my answer. How about you make your own answer so that the community can judge which way is right?"

Answer (score -20):

That's a complete misrepresentation of what happened.

**I have never encouraged anyone to write MT code based on volatile.** I have not implied that volatile is the valid solution to most thread synchronization problems.

I have not said that I wrote whole MT programs using volatile, either.

I made **a very small point** about an utterly false, and absurd claim: a claim that put together (async signal handling and portable code) and (MMIO and portable code). These two domains are the space of extremely non portable (and non standard based) code.

Of course volatile and portable often don't go together.

Also, "portable" and "described in the C standard" are *not* synonyms.

EDIT

I didn't want to go back to this, but as the OP isn't deleting his false claim about the invented claim I never made, I need to add that not only he called my arguments a "rant", he also dismissed them as "emotional".

He implies that I suggested that volatile could be used out of the allegedly blessed, portable set of {MMIO, signals, setjmp}, that was because I didn't understand the subject and that he did. But he refused on engage on thread signaling or volatile (lack of) atomicity.

Comment: We can see the comment trail ourselves.

Comment: Both at SO and here.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica The answer is MU as **the question is wrong**

Comment: If you want to disagree with an existing answer to a question, please **post your own answer** to that question. If you do not have enough evidence to compose an answer, then avoid engaging at all.

Comment: @CodyGray Why should I let an incorrect claim unchallenged?

Comment: No one is saying that you should. I gave you a specific recommendation of how to challenge an incorrect answer: write another one that points out the errors and corrects them.